# Composer post-install-cmd php script doesn't wait for input

Tags: php, command-line-interface, composer-php

So I have a console script i want run after composer has run an install.

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php vendor/bin/setup.php"
    ]
}
```

my setup.php is a CLI script that now looks like

```
<?php
    echo "something: ";
    $foo = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    echo "you said " . $foo;
?>
```

When I run `php vendor/bin/setup.php` manually form the command line - no problems. As expected. However when I run `composer install` the file executes but STDIN does not wait for a response.

Comment: FYI: I'm running PHP 5.4 on OSX via MAMP

Comment: Try `$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r'); $response = fgets($stdin);`. There might be a more complex issue related to `STDIN` here that we're not aware of.

Comment: unfortunately not. I have also noticed this will happen simply running the commands themselves via `composer run-script post-install-cmd`

Comment: Well i have a solution..in case anyone needs it: quite elegant in my scenario even though i'm still scratching my head about what was going on in the above. 
    `"scripts": {
     "post-install-cmd": [
         "MyProject\\Namespaced\\Object::StaticMethod"
     ]
    }` 
seemed to do the trick.